# There is no jersey support for @xmlheader annotation with moxy jaxb implementation

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, glassfish, moxy

I updated jersey with glassfish update tool for glassfish 3.1.1 and tried to run it with moxy JAXB RI and got the following:

> WARNING: @XmlHeader annotation is not supported with this JAXB
>   implementation. Please use JAXB RI if you need this feature.

My XML representation of data is not parsed properly so I figure this is a bug.So I want to know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. It obviously looks like @xmlWrapper annotation from the standard jaxb api does not seat well with Moxy. So removing this annotation resolved parsing issues.

Comment: Do you have an example demonstrating this?  I lead the MOXy implementation and I'm not aware of any `@XmlElementWrapper` issues.